# React Native : FlatList refreshing not showing when it's true during first load

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I ran into a problem whereby my refresh indicator not showing even the state is true in my constructor. But it's showing during a button click.

Below are my code

```
class ProductList extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      productList: null,
      refreshing: true,
    }
  }

  async componentWillMount() {

  }

  async _handleRefresh() {
    console.log('test');
    this.setState({ refreshing: false });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor:'#EFEFF4' }}>    
        <View style={{ flexDirection:'row',backgroundColor:'#fff',borderBottomWidth:0.5,borderBottomColor:'#cbd2d9' }}>
          <Text style={{ padding:10, fontFamily:'open-sans-regular'  }}>{this.state.searchText}</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity style={{ marginLeft:'auto',padding:10 }} 
              onPress={() => this.setState({ refreshing: true }) }>
            <Text style={{ color:'#6391c0', fontFamily:'open-sans-regular' }}>Search</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>     
        <FlatList
          data={this.state. productList}
          renderItem={(item) => <CustomList navigation={this.props.navigation} data={item} />}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
           ={this.state.refreshing}
          onRefresh={() => this._handleRefresh()}
          ListEmptyComponent={() =>  
            <View style={{ flex:1, justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center' }}>
              <Text style={{ marginTop: 150 }}>No records found, try search again!</Text>
            </View> 
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default ProductList;
```

This component will be using in my React-Native-Tab-View component which Is below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View , Text, StyleSheet, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import MyProductList from '../profile/myProductList';
import { TabViewAnimated, TabBar } from 'react-native-tab-view';

class MyProduct extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        headerTitle : 'My Product'
    });

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            index: 0,
            routes: [
              { key: 'upComing', title: 'Up coming' },
              { key: 'completed', title: 'Completed' },
            ],
          };
    }

    _handleIndexChange = index => this.setState({ index });

    _renderHeader = props => (
        <TabBar 
            indicatorStyle={{ backgroundColor:'#0079BF'}} 
            style={{ backgroundColor:'#FFFFFF' }} 
            tabStyle={{ padding:5 }}
            labelStyle={{ color:'black',fontWeight:'bold', fontSize:15, fontFamily:'open-sans-bold' }}
            getLabelText={({ route }) => route.title}
            {...props} />
    );

    _renderLabel = ({ route }) => (
        <Text>{route.title}</Text>
    );

    _renderScene = ({ route, focused }) => {
        switch (route.key) {
          case 'upComing': {
            return < ProductList focused={focused} navigation={this.props.navigation} />;
          }
          case 'completed':
            return < ProductList focused={focused} navigation={this.props.navigation} type={1} />;
          default:
            return null;
        }
    };  

    render() {
        return (
            <TabViewAnimated
                navigationState={this.state}
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
                renderHeader={this._renderHeader}
                onIndexChange={this._handleIndexChange}
                animationEnabled={false}
                swipeEnabled={false}
            />
        );
    }
}

export default MyProduct;
```

The refresh indicator not showing even I've set the refreshing state to true in ProductList. But if I manually trigger from button click, it will show.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @JanithaR can't find any solution yet, so i use <ActivityIndicator> for the first load and then use refreshing state for the sub sequence action. As i think first load <ActivityIndicator> is almost same as the flat list refresh, user will not notice it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe doesn't work because you're not implementing **refreshing** property.

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.props.productList }
    refreshing={ this.props.isLoading }
    onRefresh={ this._onHandleRefresh }
    renderItem={ ({item}) => this._renderListViewRow(item) }
    keyExtractor={ item => item.id } />
```

Another way to render a loading indicator inside flatlist could be using ListFooterComponent and looks like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={ this.props.productList }
    refreshing={ false }
    onRefresh={ this._onHandleRefresh }
    ListFooterComponent={ this._renderFooter }
    renderItem={ ({item}) => this._renderListViewRow(item) }
    keyExtractor={ item => item.id } />
```

and _renderFooter is a method with a simple logic

```
_renderFooter() {
    if (!this.props.isLoading) return null;

    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'column', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', paddingVertical: 10 }}>
            <ActivityIndicator animating size="small" />
        </View>
    );
}
```

In this case, I'm using redux, so basically I have 3 different states (request, success and fail) .. and when I trigger "request", this.props.isLoading is true, and when is "success" or "fail" I change this.props.isLoading to false.

btw this is using **React Native v0.53.0**

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering this question for future visitors.

In my situation the refreshing indicator was not showing at the beginning because the `FlatList` and the `View` that wrap the `FlatList` haven't `flex: 1`, so the list and its wrapper without content has no height.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
  <FlatList
    data={content}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <PostsItem {...item} uri={uri} entrypoint={entrypoint} />
    )}
    onRefresh={() => setPostsPage(1)}
    refreshing={loading}
    onEndReached={fetchMorePosts}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  />
</View>
```

Resolved like this:

```
<View style={[styles.container, {flex: 1}]}>
  <FlatList
    style={{flex: 1}}
    data={content}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id.toString()}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
      <PostsItem {...item} uri={uri} entrypoint={entrypoint} />
    )}
    onRefresh={() => setPostsPage(1)}
    refreshing={loading}
    onEndReached={fetchMorePosts}
    onEndReachedThreshold={0.1}
  />
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Now with Animated.FlatList loader-refreshing and onRefresh working.
Try like this:

```
<Animated.FlatList
    data={items}
    keyExtractor={(item) => item._id}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <Item item={item} />
    )}
    onRefresh={Auth.events}
    refreshing={loading.events}
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

For future users that the flex thing also don't work... I "tricked" it by using empty state.

```js
    <FlatList
      data={addresses}
      onRefresh={loadData}
      ListEmptyComponent={() => {
        if(isLoading) {
          return(
            <ActivityIndicator size={'large'} />
          );
        }
        return(
          <Center flex={1}>
            <Text>no addresses</Text>
          </Center>
        );
      }}
      refreshing={isLoading}
      renderItem={renderAddress}
    />
```

Not ideal, but works. Except maybe when there are actually no data, and user's pull to refresh, then you'll have 2 indicators. Maybe track that with another boolean? This is not a big issue for my case.